# PHP - Cannot parse JSON string with "."

Tags: php, json

I have a simple JSON file:

```
{
"json.transactionDetails":{
 "transactionDate":1266518024,
 "transactionType":"bought",
 "userDescription":"reimbursement",
 "transactionDescription":"Bought 10 AAPL @200",
 "quantity":10,
 "amount":"2010.00",
 "price":"200.00",
 "commission":"10.00",
}
}
```

Then a PHP file getting the JSON:

```
$t_detail = file_get_contents("details.json");
$transaction_detail = json_decode($t_detail);
$tr_detail = $transaction_detail->json.transactionDetails; //this is my issue

$transaction_type = $tr_detail->transactionType;
$user_description = $tr_detail->userDescription;
```

How do I parse the "json.transactionDetails"? The period is causing my script to fail. If I remove the "json." from both scripts everything works fine. Is there a way to skip over the first object in the tree or what? I can't change the way the JSON is outputted because it's coming from and external API.

Comment: the `.` is the concatenation operator in php. You would need to specify the key as `$transaction_detail->{"json.transactionDetails"}`

Comment: I'd suggest doing `json_decode($t_detail, TRUE);`.  This will make PHP give you an array instead of an object, then you can do `$transaction_detail['json.transactionDetails']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to

```
$transaction_detail = json_decode($t_detail,true);
$tr_detail = $transaction_detail['json.transactionDetails'];
```

When you make 2 nd parameter of `json_decode` to true , it will parse the json as an array so you can simply get the values using `array['key']` syntax

or you can

```
$transaction_detail = json_decode($t_detail);
$tr_detail = $transaction_detail->{"json.transactionDetails"};
```

Comment: I tried both suggestions and still not getting anything.

Comment: try $transaction_detail->{"json.transactionDetails"};